# How to assert attribute of contents of a list using Assertj?

Tags: unit-testing, assertions, hamcrest, assertj

Such is the method.

```
List<User> someMethod() {
    User user[] = new Users[3];
    user[0] = new User();
    user[0].setImage(new Image(Constants.HOME));
    user[1] = new User();
    user[1].setImage(new Image(Constants.NOT_HOME));
    user[2] = new User();
    user[2].setImage(new Image(Constants.HOME));   
    return Arrays.asList(user);
}
```

How can I test the test the above code. I need to verify that some of the users have images on HOME.

I could try to re-build entire users list and compare it. But, I do not want to do that.

I tried something like this,

```
assertThat(Optional.of(service.someMethod())).hasValueSatisfying((a)->a.stream().allMatch((b)->b.getImage().getImageUrl().equals(Constants.HOME)));
```

The assertion is always true in this context, because the `hasValueSatisfying` is using `Consumer<T>` as parameter. But, I want to use in in the following way - [AssertJ way](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-news.html#assertj-core-3.6.0-hasValueSatisfying)

Can I use Hamcrest in some way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use AssertJ [extracting feature](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#extracted-properties-assertion):

```
assertThat(users).extracting(user -> getImage().getImageUrl())
                 .contains(Constants.HOME)
```

I'm assuming here that users is a `List<User>` not an optional of `List<User>`.

Comment: How can I verify if all have the `Constants.HOME` or any particular number have that?

Comment: `containsOnly(Constants.HOME)`, I would suggest to explore the AssertJ API by yourself or look at assertj examples (https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-examples/tree/master/assertions-examples/src/test/java/org/assertj/examples).